# exception: 'Scalar is not in the interval [1, n - 1] (Parameter 'd')' while reading private key string to private key

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

I have a private key string, I want to read it into private key, it is sm2 algorithm using bouncy castle to read:

```
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKeyString); 
    BigInteger privateKey = new BigInteger(data);
             
   ECPrivateKeyParameters privateKeyParams = new ECPrivateKeyParameters(privateKey, sm2Parameters);
```

once the code execute the create ECPrivateKeyParameters instance, it throw
exception: 'Scalar is not in the interval [1, n - 1] (Parameter 'd')'

what is the issue?

I tried different way to generate private key string, but none of them succeeds.

Comment: This is the line of code that raises the actual error: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/crypto/parameters/ECDomainParameters.cs#L144. There are some odd things about that entire validation routine because it appears to be a rather naive port from Java. Still, the most likely reason you received the error is that you have bad data in your byte array

Comment: Try `BigInteger privateKey = new BigInteger(1, data)`. If the problem persists, post sample data.